# Is it possible to use PDO instead of Doctrine in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I'm doing a simple MVC web app that is supposed to do different queries to a SQL database. I'm using `Symfony 4` as a framework, mostly to take advantage of its routing features.

I know I could take advantage from Doctrine but I was wondering: if someone wants to use `PDO` instead of Doctrine is it possible to do so and how should it be implemented. Should I make a Database class with PDO that I could pass on to another class?

Comment: you cant compare the 2. One is an ORM, one is a database driver.  Its like trying to compare public transport as a whole, to driving a car.

Comment: Actually not comparing and still quite a junior developer to tell one thing from another. Thanks for clarifying anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are not required to use doctrine at all. You can just define your own service with required functionality.

But maybe you could use [DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal) which is lower layer used by doctrine to handle creating queries (but doesn't include any ORM functionality).

Comment: Okay, I'm still quite unfamiliar on how Symfony and Doctrine works, but this seems a legit way of proceeding. Thanks for suggesting the use of DBAL.

Comment: Doctrine is forking DBAL away from PDO